# JArray to c# Object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this json string:

```
[
   {
      "id":"EORDERING_GRE017",
      "name":"DELIMITER",
      "value":"|"
   },
   {
      "id":"EORDERING_GRE017",
      "name":"ENABLED",
      "value":"Y"
   },
   {
      "id":"EORDERING_GRE017",
      "name":"EXTERNALERRORRECIPIENT",
      "value":"jaymie@moo.co.uk; matt@moo.co.uk"
   },
   {
      "id":"EORDERING_GRE017",
      "name":"FILETYPE",
      "value":"delimited"
   },
   {
      "id":"EORDERING_GRE017",
      "name":"INTERNALERRORRECIPIENT",
      "value":"jaymie@moo.co.uk; matt@moo.co.uk"
   },
   {
      "id":"EORDERING_GRE017",
      "name":"USESOWNBRANCHCODES",
      "value":"True"
   },
   {
      "id":"EORDERING_GRE017",
      "name":"USESOWNSKUS",
      "value":"True"
   }
]
```

And I would like to turn that json into my class, which looks like this:

```
public class Settings
{
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public string Delimiter { get; set; }
    public string OrderFileSuffix { get; set; }
    public string ResultFileSuffix { get; set; }
    public bool UseOwnBranchCodes { get; set; }
    public bool UseOwnProductCodes { get; set; }
    public string InternalContacts { get; set; }
    public string ExternalContacts { get; set; }
}
```

But I am unsure which is the best way to do this. Can someone give me a hand? :)

Comment: What did you try already? "Best way" is very opinion-based, isn´t it? There are plenty of ways that mostly include some JSON-serializer, e.g. Newtonsoft.

Comment: Open Visual Studio menu => **Edit > Paste special > Paste JSON as Classes** and use Json.Net library.

Comment: I should update my question, I am using newtonsoft. I am doing something pretty ugly atm. I am deserializing into a list of anonymous objects and then looping through properties of my settings class and trying to find a match with the list item "name" and then assigning the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `NameValue` object:

```
public class NameValuePair
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize the json array to List and convert it to Dictionary:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NameValuePair>>(json).ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value);
```

Then create a custom converter class with a method that accepts this dictionary and returns a Settings object:

```
public class SettingsConverter
{
    public Settings Convert(IDictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        return new Settings
        {
            Enabled = data["ENABLED"].Equals("Y", StringComparison.Ordinal),
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The JSON is an array of objects that would fit this class:

```
public class Setting
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

So deserialize into that:

```
var settingList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Setting[]>(jsonString);
```

But then you want to map specific settings to specific properties of that `Settings` class. You could do that by trying to find the particular setting for each property in the list of settings:

```
var settingsObject = new Settings
{
    FileType = settingList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "FILETYPE")?.Value,
    Delimiter = settingList.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "DELIMITER")?.Value,
    // ...
}
```

You'll *have* to manually map the properties. If you don't want that, you could write a custom serializer, but that'll quickly become a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

For those out there that may need some more help with the JSON Class Configuration, try: http://json2csharp.com/#

An excellent way of Auto Generating the Classes!

Or even easier, in VS, Goto:

> Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste as JSON Classes